# Error: tunnel unavailable: failed probing "personal": context deadline exceeded

Tags: ssh, console, fly

I'm trying to ssh into my fly instance, but getting a strange error. This has always worked in the past without issue.

```
fly ssh console
Connecting to tunnel Error: tunnel unavailable: failed probing "personal": context deadline exceeded
```

another attempt

```
fly ssh console -C "app/bin/rails c"
Connecting to tunnel Error: tunnel unavailable: failed probing "personal": context deadline exceeded
```

It sounded like some sort of port/socket issue, so I rebooted and checked that no firewall, VPN, or similar software was interferring.

What's going on?

Answer (score 11):

After a few hours of messing about, I updated flyctl (with `brew upgrade flyctl`), started a new terminal, and tried again but still go the error.

Then I tried making a small change to the repo and running `fly deploy`. That's when I saw:

```
fly deploy     
==> Verifying app config
Validating fly.toml
Platform: machines
✓ Configuration is valid
--> Verified app config
==> Building image
WARN Failed to start remote builder heartbeat: Your account has been marked as high risk. Please go to https://fly.io/high-risk-unlock to verify your account.
Error: failed to fetch an image or build from source: error connecting to docker: Your account has been marked as high risk. Please go to https://fly.io/high-risk-unlock to verify your account.
```

So I had to go here and verify my credit card: https://fly.io/high-risk-unlock

Then I saw a similar error to the original one:

```
fly deploy
==> Verifying app config
Validating fly.toml
Platform: machines
✓ Configuration is valid
--> Verified app config
==> Building image
WARN Failed to start remote builder heartbeat: failed building options: failed probing "personal": context deadline exceeded
Error: failed to fetch an image or build from source: error connecting to docker: failed building options: failed probing "personal": context deadline exceeded
```

I ran this:

```
fly wireguard websockets enable
```

which I found [here](https://community.fly.io/t/eror-failed-to-start-remote-builder-heartbeat-failed-building-options-failed-probing-personal-context-deadline-exceeded/10708/3), then everything worked.

Comment: This was a lifesaver. Thanks!

Comment: Strange one. Seems like a bug - hope it's on their radar. Thanks for saving me a ton of debug time.